# Why won't ComplexExpand remove Abs from my function, how can I do this?

Tags: functions

These are my inputs and the resulting output:

```
r1[t] := {x1[t], y1[t]}
r2[t] := {x2[t], y2[t]}
v1[t] := D[r1[t], t]
v2[t] := D[r2[t], t]
vCM := (v1[t] + v2[t])/2

Irod := 1/12 m (5 b)^2

T1[t] = FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[1/2 m Norm[vCM[t]]^2]]
(* 1/2 m Abs[{1/2 (Derivative[1][x1][t] + Derivative[1][x2][t]), 
    1/2 (Derivative[1][y1][t] + Derivative[1][y2][t])}[t]]^2 *)
```

I'd want to know how I can remove the `Abs[...]` from the final result.

Comment: @corey979 when do you need to use underscore _ when defining functions?

Comment: Could specifiy `TargetFunctions->{Re,Im}` to `ComplexExpand`. That way it will work to avoid `Abs`, `Arg`, `Sign`, and `Conjugate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`Blank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html) pattern object in your function definitions

```
r1[t_] := {x1[t], y1[t]}
r2[t_] := {x2[t], y2[t]}
v1[t_] := D[r1[t], t]
v2[t_] := D[r2[t], t]
vCM[t_] := (v1[t] + v2[t])/2

FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[1/2 m Norm[vCM[t]]^2]]

(*  1/8 m ((Derivative[1][x1][t] + 
     Derivative[1][x2][t])^2 + (Derivative[1][y1][t] + 
     Derivative[1][y2][t])^2)  *)
```